# How to force an iFrame to reload once it loads

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, refresh, reload

I have numerous iframes that load specific content on my pages. Both the parent and iframe are on the same domain.

I have a scrollbar inside the iframe that doesn't seem to load correctly in all browsers. But when I refresh the iframe it loads perfect. I have no idea why it does this.

I have used the meta refresh, which works but I don't want the page to refresh constantly, just once.

The solution I'm looking for will reload the iFrame content after the iFrame is opened, with a minimal delay.

---

### Edit

I realized that my page loads all of my iframes when the index is loaded. The iframes appear in a jQuery overlay, which is also loaded but visibility:hidden until called. So on this call is when I would want the iframe to be reloaded.

Could anyone help me come up with a Javascript function that reloads the iFrame when I click the link to the iFrame? I've gotten close but I know nothing about js and I keep falling short. I have a function that reloads the page, but I can't figure out how to get it called just once.

I have this so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var pl;
var change;
pl=1;

function ifr() {

if (pl=1) {
    document.location.reload([true]);
    alert("Page Reloaded!");
    change=1;
    return change;
}

change+pl;

}
```

So basically it uses the document.location.reload which works to reload the page. I'm trying to then make pl change to something other than 1 so the function doesnt run again. I've been calling this JS from the body with onLoad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the leads on this went dead, but I did find a code snippet that worked. Not written by me, and I don't remember where it came from. Just posting to help someone should they ever have the same question.

```
<div class="overlay-content"> //Content container needed for CSS Styling
    <div id="Reloader"> 
        //iFrame will be reloaded into this div
    </div>

    //Script to reload the iframe when the page loads
    <script>
        function aboutReload() { 
            $("#Reloader").html('<iframe id="Reloader" height="355px" width="830px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="about.html"></iframe>');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Basically just loads the iFrame source when the window with the iFrame opens, as opposed to the iFrame loading when the original page loads.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the scope of the original question, however this jQuery snippit works with cross domain *iframe* elements where the contentDocument.location.reload(true) method won't due to sandboxing.

```
//assumes 'this' is the iframe you want to reload.
$(this).replaceWith($(this).clone()); //Force a reload
```

Basically it replaces the whole iframe element with a copy of itself. We're using it to force resize embedded 3rd party "dumb" widgets like video players that don't notice when their size changes.

Answer (score 2):

On the iframe element itself, set an onload:

```
iframe.onload = function() {this.contentWindow.location.reload(); this.onload = null;};
```

(Only works if the iframe's location is in the same domain as the main page)

Comment: I recommend using `this` instead of `iframe` inside the event handler, in case variable `iframe` gets overwritten.

Comment: Good point. Will edit. (I'm used to lots of closures, so variable names are very unlikely to be overwritten :p)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply guys! the iframe loads about.html and the parent is index.php. Do I put this code in the header of about.html inside <script> tag?

Comment: @Brett: in the parent page. This answer doesn't really make it clear where to put it, since to set iframe.onload you have to wait until the iframe is in the DOM, but if you wait for parent's "load" event, the iframe may or may be already loaded by that time.

Comment: An untested idea is to put <iframe onload="reloadOnce(this)"> in HTML; make the reloadOnce function check a flag, then if it's not set, set it and reload the frame.

Comment: @Nickolay I tried your untested idea and it didn't work. But I might have been doing it wrong. I also tried the iframe.onload as above a couple of ways and can't get it too work. I'm updating my question, I realized something new.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete solution to the original question:

```
<iframe onload="reloadOnce(this)" src="test2.html"></iframe>
<script>
var iframeLoadCount = 0;
function reloadOnce(iframe) {
  iframeLoadCount ++;
  if (iframeLoadCount <= 1) {
    iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
    console.log("reload()");
  }
}
</script>
```

The updated question is not really clear (what's "the link to the iFrame" and where is it in your snippet?), but you have a few issues with the code:

- "calling this JS from the body with onLoad", assuming you mean an iframe's body, means the variable you're hoping to use to avoid infinite reloading will get clobbered along with the rest of the iframe's page when it's reloaded. You need to either load a slightly different URL in the iframe (and check the URL on iframe's onload before reloading) or put the flag variable in the outer page (and access it with `parent.`*variableName* - that should work I think)
- `if (pl=1) {` should use `==`, as `=` is always an assignment.
- `change+pl;` has no effect.

Comment: Let me try to clear up the "link to iFrame"... When a visitor clicks a link to additional content on, for example, the "about" page, the additional content is displayed through an iFrame. so the "iFrame link" would be any of the links on the "about" page (which would be "about me" "about you" "faq" and so on) ... These additional pages are what use the iFrames. All of the iFrames get loaded on the initial visit to the index.php page. But when called up by click their respective link, I need them to refresh. I will try out this solution. Thank you for your time on this issue!

Comment: I tried to put your code in, but it didn't work. Did I implement this correctly?
`code
<iframe height="425px" width="830px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="about-homeopathy.html" onload="reloadOnce(this)"></iframe>
 `   
         `code  
<script>
var iframeLoadCount = 0;
function reloadOnce(iframe) {
  iframeLoadCount ++;
  if (iframeLoadCount <= 1) {
    iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
    console.log("reload()");
  }
}
</script>
`

Comment: This works for me - I added the script right above the iframe and then that onload attribute. Worked like a charm!