# How to autoload iframe elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a portfolio page that embeds around 12 iframe elements. I am wondering if there is a way to cache or autoload the iframe elements so that I do not need to reload every time the website loads.

Here are what my iframe elements look like:

`<iframe src="http://iframe.url" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

The iframe element houses banner advertisements, consisting of images, HTML, and JS code. Please let me know how to accomplish this task. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to change the iframe src attribute with jQuery? `$("#some-iframe").attr("src", "http://iframe.url");`?

Comment: So you have a 'set' of adverts in iFrames, and you'd essentially like to change one advert to another without the user refreshing the page? You're definitely looking for AfikDeri's line above to change the iFrame. I'll add to this by saying you're looking for a `setTimeout()` function that will automatically replace them over time. Build an array of the links, and pass that into a loop that changes the src attribute based on loop index over time :)

Comment: Thank you for those replies. Unfortunately, I do not want to swap out the images, I still want them to be visible in separate iFrames (currently they are in buckets) but I'd like them to load faster especially on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quoting the information here.  If I understand what you are wanting, this looked promising.

> > Friendly Iframe
> >
> > This technique is for ads. It's not really an iframe loading
> >     technique, but more of a way to use an iframe to hold ads. The magic
> >     is not in how the iframe is loaded, but in how the main page, the
> >     iframe and ad codes work together. It works like this:
>
> 1. Create an iframe. Set the source to a small static html page from the same domain
> 2. Inside the iframe, set the JavaScript variable inDapIF = true to tell the ad it is loaded inside a friendly iframe
> 3. Inside the iframe, create an script element with the ad url as the source. Load the ad just like a normal JavaScript ad
> 4. When the ad has finished loading, resize the iframe to fit the dimensions of the ad.
>
> The Friendly Iframe works in all browsers.

There were other techniques listed, but this seem to fit your use case. See the other methods at [Iframe loading techniques and performance](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance?%3E)

If you are wanting a method to force the iFrame to reload, here is an SO answer on that. [How to force an iFrame to reload once it loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851727/how-to-force-an-iframe-to-reload-once-it-loads)

Comment: This really seemed to speed up my ad load time! Thank you!

Comment: No problem!  Glad I was able to help.  I know what it feels like to spend lots of time futzing with iFrames.

Answer (score 1):

You can set html meta tag for url in iframe.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES"
CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2018 11:12:01 GMT">
```

This will cache the results of iframe.

Even you can use AJAX to load the contents. This will not reload the entire page, instead i will change contents dynamically. Cache AJAX results to save bandwidth.

Comment: If you are adding more of an explanation, **edit** your answer instead of leaving a comment. Refer to **When should I comment?** and **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [comment everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where would I add this code?